How Can I Scale Token Distribution in an INK! Custody Smart Contract Using OpenBrush?
community! I am a beginner in INK! and I am developing a custody contract using OpenBrush. This contract receives token (X) as collateral for another token (Y) contract. At regular intervals, the holders of token (Y) can vote to decide whether to maintain the collateral or not. If the vote decides not to maintain the collateral, token (X) will be distributed to the wallets holding token (Y).
We are facing difficulties in making this scalable, especially in identifying the wallets with a balance of token (Y) and distributing token (X) to them. How can I implement this distribution efficiently and scalably in the contract?
I appreciate any guidance or code examples you can provide!

The telegram channel is also a good place for these questions: https://t.me/inkathon/569

From just quickly reading your question. If it is decided to not hold the collateral why don't you do it in the way that the token holders have to request the collateral via an ink message. In that way you can check in the contract what the balance of the requester is and send the tokens that it deserves.
